# Nginx returns 404 unless adding `try_files $uri @proxy;`

Tags: nginx

I am deploying a proxy using Nginx, and get a little confused.

Following is my original config file:

```
server {
    server_name xxx;
    listen 80;

    location @proxy {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9099;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
            proxy_read_timeout 10s;
        }
}
```

which results in 404.

However, if I add a

```
try_files $uri @proxy;
```

before the `location` block, i.e.

```
server {
    server_name funfact.wechat.fantwan.com;
    listen 80;

    // The new line
    try_files $uri @proxy;

    location @proxy {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9099;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
            proxy_read_timeout 10s;
        }
}
```

then everything goes fine.

The code is copied from the internet, and I am not sure why it works. I believe `try_files` is trying to find a file located at `$uri`, but not clear what `@proxy` means, and what exactly are `$xxx` and `@xxx`.

Could anyone provide me some explanation?

Comment: "from the internet" where exactly? The internet isn't a small place

Comment: @Isaac, just mean copied from a tutorial online.

Comment: Use `location /` instead of `location @proxy`. You have defined a *named location* with no way to invoke it! See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The [NGINX beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) is a good place to start learning about NGINX.

Comment: not exactly an answer. I could link to google and say it is a good place to start learning about NGINX